# Configure basic python 3.5, flask, uwsgi, nginx app

Tags: nginx, web-server, python, uwsgi, flask

Not sure where I am going wrong here, all I get is a 502 bad gateway. (server ip is 104.197.13.112)
The code for all the configuration files and basic app are in a github repo.
[github repo](https://github.com/vincentdavis/test-flask-ngix-uwsgi)

nginx seems to start correctly, uwsgi does not and I think my problem is with my uwsgi setup and uwsgi.ini. Also not in the log below, my virtual env is python 3.5 and below the error reports 3.4.2. I have uwsgi installed in my virtual env. (Update, I got the uwsgi installed in my virtual env to be run by the virtual env rather than the system python by sylinking the uwsgi in /usr/bin/uwsgi to the uwsgi in the env.) The log below reflects that but the error is otherwise the same

The log shows

```
(testenv)root@co-data-nginx-1:/# tail /var/log/uwsgi/app/flasktest.log
Wed Jan 13 03:39:39 2016 - uwsgi socket 1 bound to UNIX address /tmp/flasktest.sock fd 5
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Wed Jan 13 03:39:39 2016 - Python version: 3.5.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:16:01)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
Wed Jan 13 03:39:39 2016 - Set PythonHome to /var/www/flasktest/testenv
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
uwsgi does not start.
```

uwsgi does not start

```
(testenv)root@co-data-nginx-1:/# service uwsgi restart
Job for uwsgi.service failed. See 'systemctl status uwsgi.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
(testenv)root@co-data-nginx-1:/# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Tue 2016-01-12 23:46:30 UTC, end at Wed 2016-01-13 03:58:07 UTC. --
Jan 13 03:58:04 co-data-nginx-1 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s)...
-- Subject: Unit uwsgi.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit uwsgi.service has begun starting up.
Jan 13 03:58:04 co-data-nginx-1 uwsgi[7065]: Starting app server(s): uwsgi -> ! failed!
Jan 13 03:58:04 co-data-nginx-1 systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 13 03:58:04 co-data-nginx-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s).
-- Subject: Unit uwsgi.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit uwsgi.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jan 13 03:58:04 co-data-nginx-1 systemd[1]: Unit uwsgi.service entered failed state.
Jan 13 03:58:06 co-data-nginx-1 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s)...
-- Subject: Unit uwsgi.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit uwsgi.service has begun starting up.
Jan 13 03:58:07 co-data-nginx-1 uwsgi[7207]: Starting app server(s): uwsgi -> ! failed!
Jan 13 03:58:07 co-data-nginx-1 systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 13 03:58:07 co-data-nginx-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s).
-- Subject: Unit uwsgi.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit uwsgi.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jan 13 03:58:07 co-data-nginx-1 systemd[1]: Unit uwsgi.service entered failed state.
```

Trying test @gf_ suggested, run:

```
 uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/flasktest.ini
```

I get the output below, this looks good but (remember I am running as root) if I login as another user I can only run the above line is I ass sudo. If I do add sudo it does not work, getting bacicly thte same error as in the uwsgi log.

```
(testenv)root@co-data-nginx-1:/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled# uwsgi --ini flasktest.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from flasktest.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit) on [Wed Jan 13 21:54:35 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.9.2 on 12 January 2016 23:28:38
os: Linux-3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u2 (2016-01-02)
nodename: co-data-nginx-1
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
detected binary path: /var/www/flasktest/testenv/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
chdir() to /var/www/flasktest
your processes number limit is 14779
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 65536
VirtualHosting mode enabled.
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/flasktest.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.5.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:16:01)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
Set PythonHome to /var/www/flasktest/testenv
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x192cb40
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 436560 bytes (426 KB) for 5 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x192cb40 pid: 17933 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 17933)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 17935, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 17936, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 17937, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 17938, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 17939, cores: 1)
```

In /etc/uwsgi/apps-avalible (enabled) I have.

```
(testenv)root@co-data-nginx-1:/# cat /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/flasktest.ini
# To be put in /etc/uwsgi/apps-available and lnked to the apps-enabled
# mv /var/www/flasktest/config/flasktest.ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/
# and simlink into
# ln -s /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/flasktest /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled

[uwsgi]
module = testapp
callable = app
vhost = true
venv = /var/www/flasktest/testenv
chdir = /var/www/flasktest
master = true
processes = 5
socket = /tmp/%n.sock
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

And finally, here is the nginx setup, again all of this is in the github repo.

```
(testenv)root@co-data-nginx-1:/# cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/flasktest
# rm /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
# rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
# mv /var/www/flasktest/config/flasktest /etc/nginx/sites-available/
# and simlink into
# ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/flasktest /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

# now test setup
# nginx -t
# If it passes run
# service nginx restart

server {
    listen 80;
    server_tokens off;
    # ip address or domain
    # server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com
    server_name 104.197.13.112;

    location /static {
         alias /var/www/flasktest/static;
     }

     location / {
         include uwsgi_params;
         uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/flasktest.sock;
         include uwsgi_params;
     }
```

nginx logs

```
2016/01/13 02:34:03 [error] 4417#0: *2 connect() to unix:///tmp/flasktest.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 24.52.34.170, server: 104.197.13.112, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/flasktest.sock:", host: "104.197.13.112"
2016/01/13 02:34:04 [error] 4417#0: *2 connect() to unix:///tmp/flasktest.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 24.52.34.170, server: 104.197.13.112, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/flasktest.sock:", host: "104.197.13.112", referrer: "http://104.197.13.112/"
```

Comment: 1.) Don't run your webapplications as root; there is a hint as well in your logfile regarding this. 2.) Whats the question exactly?

Comment: @gf_ my question is how do I get it to work, rather than a 502 error. I agree with the don't run as root and I see the warning. Not sure how best to fix that, but wanted to first get the app to run. I am used to seeing /var/www owned by www-data but in this case, they are not so I left it alone.

Comment: "Connection refused": Did you make sure, that `uwsgi` is running?

Comment: Did you saw the "Fatal Python error" in your `uwsgi` log? I guess, `uwsgi` isn't correctly running because of this. In the log you've provided earlier wasn't an error like this. Any idea, where this is coming from? Anyway, this should be fixed...

Comment: added output from # service uwsgi restart.
I see the Fatal Python error, Not sure why I am getting the error or why it is using the system python to run uwsgi. How do I get uswgi to use the virtual env.

Comment: Could you run `uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/flasktest.ini` and show the output? (Going to sleep _now_... :])

Comment: Vincent, which OS are you running?

Comment: Also: If you run `uwsgi` manually, as you did, is the rest of your setup working as expected?

Comment: So, in case this is `Debian`: You want to use the `emperor` mode of `uwsgi`, right? Make sure, that the file / symlink in `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled` has an `.ini` extension. According to your code above, you're missing this extension; besides this, I strongly belief that the symlink you've created is broken, because it points to `/etc/uwsgi/apps-available/flasktest`, whereas it should point to `/etc/uwsgi/apps-available/flasktest.ini`.

Comment: Try to fix this, restart `uwsgi` and give feedback please!

Comment: @gf_ google cloud vm Debain. I updated question to show files(links) in apps-enabled. emperor? looked at docs, not sure what to do with that. I'll owe you something when this is working. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Alright, looks sane. Could you do `systemctl restart uwsgi.service` now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34268/discussion-between-vincent-and-gf).

Answer (score 1):

Let's go...

- Remove `/var/www/flasktest/uwsgi.ini`, you don't need this.
- `uwsgi`:

  - ...can't bind to your socket; change the `socket` directive in your `uwsgi.ini` to `/tmp/%n.sock`. `%n` will get evaluated to the name of the config file, sans extension.
  - Does `uwsgi` work if you start it? Have a look inside the logs; if you'll find errors, please post these.
- `Nginx`:

  - Change your `uwsgi_pass` directive to `uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/flasktest.sock` and insert `include uwsgi_params;` at the next line.
  - Reverse the order of the `/` and `/static` config blocks to make sure these work as expected. As it stands, `/` will be hit for all requests, including `/static`, so these would be served by your backend, which isn't wise to do, given the files being served are static and not dynamic.

Comment: @Vincent It's quite late over here, will go to sleep now. If you're experiencing problems, please post a comment or update your original post. Will have a look again in some hours..

Comment: Updated question based on changes you suggested.